# Generate multiple random numbers PHP

Tags: php, random

I want to create multiple random numbers. Is there a loop that I could use to create this? I do not want to use this coding below:

```
$random1 = rand(1000,9999);
$random2 = rand(1000,9999);
$random3 = rand(1000,9999);
$random4 = rand(1000,9999);
$random5 = rand(1000,9999);
$random6 = rand(1000,9999);
$random7 = rand(1000,9999);
```

Comment: Yes there is a loop: `$random = []; for($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) { $random[] = mt_rand(1000,9999); }`

Comment: Create multiple random numbers for the purpose of... ? What you are doing is the correct way. Depending on your ultimate goal/need, there may be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$random = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $random[$i] = rand(1000,9999);
}
```

This will generate an array $random with 7 elements containing random number at index 0-6.

Answer (score 0):

```
$random = array();
$start = 1000;
$end = 9999;
$count = 7;
while(count($random) < $count){
    $rand = rand($start, $end);
    $random[$rand] = $rand;
}
```

The index will be the same as the random number, to guarantee no duplicate random numbers.